# Using InputRadio with bool values

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have an `InputRadio` control that looks like the following:

```
<InputRadioGroup Name="FooBar" @bind-Value="Foo.Bar">
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value=1 />Yes<br>
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value=0 />No<br>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

`Foo.Bar` is currently a nullable `int` because it appears that an `int` is what the built in `InputRadio` control binding expects. I would rather set `Foo.Bar` to be a nullable `bool` instead of an `int` as my app has a lot of Yes/No questions and working with true/false in the code would make things easier and more readable.

Is there a way in Blazor to configure it so the `InputRadio` control can bind to a bool value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in .NET 6:

```
<InputRadioGroup Name="FooBar" @bind-Value="@Foo.Bar">
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@true" />Yes<br>
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@false" />No<br>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

First things first, getting a boolean value is usually a checkbox, so you can try that first.

```
<EditForm Model="@Foo">

    Type: @Foo.Bar.GetType()
    <br />
    Value: @Foo.Bar
    <br /><br />

    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@Foo.Bar">I understand</InputCheckbox>

</EditForm>

@code{
    MyClass Foo { get; set; } = new MyClass();

    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool Bar { get; set; } = true;
    }
}
```

If you do have to use radio buttons, read on.

I think that this should, ideally, work with real `bool` values but it seems it does not, here is a repro (perhaps you could log it with MS in their repo) - initially it seems to parse OK, but **changing the value throws** that it can't parse from a string. This indicates to me that they only support `string` and `int` for the radio button groups.

```
<EditForm Model="@Foo">

    Type: @Foo.Bar.GetType()
    <br />
    Value: @Foo.Bar
    <br /><br />

    <InputRadioGroup Name="FooBar" @bind-Value="@Foo.Bar">
        <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@true" />Yes<br>
        <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@false" />No<br>
    </InputRadioGroup>

</EditForm>

@code{
    MyClass Foo { get; set; } = new MyClass();

    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool Bar { get; set; } = true;
    }
}
```

Solutions:

- Use an enum if you can (it is basically an integer, which is why it works)
- Use a helper field that can be parsed to the desired bool value (example below)

For the helper field to work out, you need strings that you can parse and you might need them as variables in the view-model, because just setting `Value="@true"` or `Value="true"` will actually either try to look for a field, or use the boolean value, while the HTML element matches as a string. A bit of a catch 22 with the syntax.

```
<EditForm Model="@Foo">

    Type: @Foo.Bar.GetType()
    <br />
    Value: @Foo.Bar
    <br />
    String Value @Foo.BarString
    <br /><br />

    <InputRadioGroup Name="FooBar" @bind-Value="@Foo.BarString">
        <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@trueVal" />Yes<br>
        <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@falseVal" />No<br>
    </InputRadioGroup>

</EditForm>

@code{
    string trueVal = "true";
    string falseVal = "false";
    MyClass Foo { get; set; } = new MyClass();

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string BarString { get; set; } = "true";
        public bool Bar { get { return bool.Parse(BarString); } set { BarString = value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(); } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Radio buttons are required in my case as the user **needs** to make a selection (Yes or No) and the input is required. I think using an enum is the best solution for now. I'm trying to follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#radio-buttons) for `InputRadio` but the data type saved when using the example there is a string. Still working on trying to figure that out. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: I think radio buttons only support string and int (and, thus, enum)

Comment: Yeah. I'm using an enum now (example [here](https://gist.github.com/ryanbuening/3e4ec14703154ae53a14fd0382c13e96)), but the value that is saved to the database is a string, "Yes". I would expect it to be an int (0 or 1)

Comment: This had its advantages, though. I think it's up to the database layer to decide whether to use .ToString or not though

Comment: I can confirm after a couple hours wasted that I was unable to get bool working. Message is "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean'."

Comment: I don't think it is in the design of the current radio buttons in blazor to support such values. You'd have to go through ints or strings, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**This question is already answered however maybe some people like the solution I present.**

Form a `InputRadioGroup` I expected that you could simply bind it like

```
<InputRadioGroup Name="FooBar" @bind-Value="@Foo.Bar">
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@true" />Yes<br>
    <InputRadio Name="FooBar" Value="@false" />No<br>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

And that `@Foo.Bar` would be true or false however this doesn't work.
There is a simple work around for this using `InputCheckbox` and a reversed value.

In your page write

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Foo.Bar" type="checkbox" /> Text 1
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Foo.ReversedBar" type="checkbox" /> Text 2
```

And in your `Foo` model write

```
    public bool Bar
    {
        get => _bar;
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
            _reversedBar = !value;
        }
    }
    private bool _bar;

    public bool ReversedBar
    {
        get => _reversedBar;
        set
        {
            _reversedBar = value;
            _bar = !value;
        }
    }
    private bool _reversedBar;
```

Then you could simply store the `Foo.Bar` value in your database or do whatever you want with it.

If you want that one of the values is already true on page load than you can do that like this.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Foo.Bar = true;
}
```

If you want the `InputCheckbox` to be round you can use some `css` for that.